# Android passing values to activities that have not yet started

Tags: android, android-intent

I am running into an issue with passing values to activities. I have a Title activity that launches Generating activity. Generating activity launches Play activity. Suppose I want to pass some value such as a boolean to Play activity from Title activity.

Would I have to pass it first to Generating activity and then make Generating activity pass the value to Play? Or can I pass it via `putExtra()` bypassing Generating activity even if Title activity does not launch Play activity directly?

Comment: you can use an intermediate activity or something like this to check this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An intent is a message containing data that will launch an activity.  The data is only available to the target activity.

So to answer your questions:

No, you cannot pass intent data from TileActivity to PlayActivity.  You must pass it to GeneratingActivity, who in turn would then pass it to PlayActivity.

There are alternatives to using intents such as:

1. Static/Global data - Use this with care.  Because of how Android manages your process, it can be dangerous to use this approach.
2. SharedPreferences - This is a mechanism for persisting data.  Your first activity could save the data in SharedPreferences, and the third activity could read it from SharePreferences.  Because of the dangers with approach #1 above, many people take this approach in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `public class` with a `static` variable :

```
public class Global {
   public static boolean play = false;
}
```

You just need to call `Global.play = true` in your `Title Activity` and check the value of `Global.play` in your `Play Activity` (or other `Activities` based on your need)

Comment: Note - Using static data is a dangerous thing in Android.  The system can kill your process and re-launch it at any time for memory management purposes.  If this happens during the transition between activities the static data would be lost resulting in a bug.